# How to create hourly list with datetime_range without year

Tags: python, datetime, hour

I'm trying to create list of hours contained within each specified interval, which would be quite complicated with loop. Therefore, I wanted to ask for `datetime` recommendations.

```py
# input in format DDHH/ddhh:
validity = ['2712/2812','2723/2805','2800/2812']
# demanded output:
val_hours = ['2712', '2713', '2714'..., '2717', '2723', '2800',...'2804',]
```

It would be great if last hour of validity would be considered as non-valid, becouse interval is ended by that hour, or more precisely by 59th minute of previous one.

I've tried quite complicated way with if conditions and loops, but I am persuaded that there is better one - as always.

It is something like:

```py
#input in format DDHH/ddhh:
validity = ['2712/2812','2723/2805','2800/2812']
output = []
#upbound = previsously defined function defining list of lengt of each group 
upbound = [24, 6, 12] 

#For only first 24-hour group:

for hour in range(0,upbound[0]):
      item = int(validity[0][-7:-5]) + hour
      if (hour >= 24):
           hour = hour - 24
   output = output + hour
```

Further I would have to prefix numbers with date smaller than 10, like 112 (01st 12:00 Zulu) with zero and ensure correct day.

Loops and IFs seem to me just to compúlicated. Not mentioning error handling, it looks like two or three conditions.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I gave it a shot using datetime, check if my answer makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each valid string, I use `datetime.strptime` to parse it, then based on either start date is less than or equal to end date, or greater than end date, I calculate the hours.

For start date less than or equal to end date, I consider original valid string, else I create two strings `start_date/3023` and `0100/end_date`

```
import datetime

validity = ['2712/2812','2723/2805','2800/2812','3012/0112','3023/0105','0110/0112']

def get_valid_hours(valid):

    hours_li = []
    #Parse the start date and end date as datetime
    start_date_str, end_date_str = valid.split('/')
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date_str,'%d%H')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_str, '%d%H')

    #If start date less than equal to end date
    if start_date <= end_date:
        dt = start_date
        i=0
        #Keep creating new dates until we hit end date
        while dt < end_date:
            #Append the dates to a list
            dt = start_date+datetime.timedelta(hours=i)
            hours_li.append(dt.strftime('%d%H'))
            i+=1
    #Else split the validity into two and calculate them separately
    else:
        start_date_str, end_date_str = valid.split('/')
        return get_valid_hours('{}/3023'.format(start_date_str)) + get_valid_hours('0100/{}'.format(end_date_str))

    #Append sublist to a bigger list
    return hours_li

for valid in validity:
    print(get_valid_hours(valid))
```

The output then looks like, not sure if this was the format needed!

```
['2712', '2713', '2714', '2715', '2716', '2717', '2718', '2719', '2720', '2721', '2722', '2723', '2800', '2801', '2802', '2803', '2804', '2805', '2806', '2807', '2808', '2809', '2810', '2811', '2812']
['2723', '2800', '2801', '2802', '2803', '2804', '2805']
['2800', '2801', '2802', '2803', '2804', '2805', '2806', '2807', '2808', '2809', '2810', '2811', '2812']
['3012', '3013', '3014', '3015', '3016', '3017', '3018', '3019', '3020', '3021', '3022', '3023', '0100', '0101', '0102', '0103', '0104', '0105', '0106', '0107', '0108', '0109', '0110', '0111', '0112']
['0100', '0101', '0102', '0103', '0104', '0105']
['0110', '0111', '0112']
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I am just adjusting my programe and it shows to be problem that procedure you suggested does not respect e.g. date like 3021/0105. I've tried some if condition implementation, but it produced further problems. Do you have some pyhtonic and elegant idea?
Validity do not overreach 30 hours, so 3012/0112 or 3123/0205 maximum.

Comment: I will look into it and update the code accordingly in my answer, thanks for letting me know

Comment: What is the expected output for `3021/0105`, if you can give me that, I can update my code accordingly!

Comment: For 3021/0105 it is validity from 30th day 21 hour to 1st to 5:00, so output is:
3021, 3022, 3023, 0100, 0101, 0102, 0103, 0104, 0105

Comment: Thanks so the dates roll over after 30 and goes to 1 that should be easy, let me update the answer

Comment: Okay! The code is updated, and I have removed the need of `upbound` check it out @DavidSládek and the outputs, and lemme know if solution is clear to you

Comment: If it worked for you @DavidSládek Please consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created something easy like this:

```
validity = ['3012/0112','3023/0105','0110/0112']
upbound = [24, 6, 12]

hours_list = []
for idx, val in enumerate(validity):
    hours_li = []
    DD = val[:2]
    HH = val[2:4]
    dd = val[5:7]
    hh = val[7:9]
    if DD == dd:
       for i in range(int(HH),upbound[idx]):
           hours_li.append(DD + str(i).zfill(2))
    if DD <> dd:
        for i in range(int(HH),24):
           hours_li.append(DD + str(i).zfill(2))
        for j in range(0,int(hh)):
            hours_li.append(dd + str(j).zfill(2))
    hours_list.append(hours_li)
```

This works for 24h validity (it could be solved by one if condition and similar block of concatenate), does not use datetime, just numberst and str. It is neither pythonic nor fast, but works.